# Should I normalize or de-normalize?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a table:

`Person` with columns:

```
pID(PK)
FName
LName
plID(FK)
```

Another table `Place` with:

```
plID(PK)
plCity
plState
plZip
```

Is it better to just have `Person` made like:

```
pID(PK)
FName
LName
City
State
Zip
```

For instance:

```
John Doe New York, NY 00000
Jane Doe New York, NY 00000
Jim Doe New York, NY 00000
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934577/should-i-normalize-my-db-or-not

Comment: @transistor1 - good link, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should normalize a database to eliminate data redundancy. In your case, it is very likely that you'll have a lot of people from the same place, which would cause data redundancy.

Therefore the answer is **yes**. You should absolutely normalize your database. You could possibly just include the zip code in the `Person` table and let that be a foreign key in `Person` and primary key in `Place`.

Comment: I agree.  The only gotcha is to ensure that when John Doe moves to San Francisco, CA 99999, it is only he that moves and not everyone else who was in New York, NY, 00000.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Using my proposed design, you would just change the zip code in the `Person` table to 99999. Naturally, `Place` should not be touched.

Comment: Well, I forgot to include, this table has a PersonID(PK) instead, so it would simply update where this PersonID = whatevernyzipwas to the new zip... in psuedo-sql :)