# How to find strings before string -> true?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have 'animal_check' column with values
[dog -> true, rose -> false, elephant -> true, cow -> true, daffodil -> false]

and I would like to have a result 'animal' based on above which only contains

dog,elephant,cow .

How to achieve it? Any suggestion? Thank you :)

Comment: [Should I normalize my DB or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934577/should-i-normalize-my-db-or-not), I think you should.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing multiple values in a string.  It is bad database design.

Comment: *I have 'animal_check' column with values* Precise values are unclear. Provide this as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Answer (score 0):

Without explanation (because you should normalize your database!):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(y,x,i) AS (
   SELECT space(50) as y , 'dog -> true, rose -> false, elephant -> true, cow -> true, daffodil -> false' as x, 0 as i
   UNION ALL
   SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(x,','),',',i+1),',',-1),50),x,i+1 
   FROM cte 
   WHERE i<10 and rtrim(x)<>' '
)
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(y,'-',1)) as animal 
FROM cte
WHERE y like '%true%';
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f48dda7df00a91acbbc659dc19f524f)