# mysql join: what is faster?

Tags: mysql, performance, join

My tables: big_table

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | mediumint(7) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id     | tinyint(2)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sub_category_id | tinyint(2)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| width           | smallint(5)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| height          | smallint(5)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ratio_width     | smallint(5)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ratio_height    | smallint(5)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| size            | int(8)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| mime            | tinyint(2)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| views           | mediumint(7) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| time            | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| file            | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

small_table

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id     | mediumint(7) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| width  | smallint(5)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| height | smallint(5)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

so what's faster (example):

```
   SELECT * FROM `big_table` WHERE `width` =1920 AND `height`=1080;
```

or use join

```
 select big_table.*
 from small_table
 left join small_table small_table2
 ON (small_table.id=small_table2.id
     and `small_table`.`height` = '1080')
 left join big_table
 ON (big_table.id=small_table.id)
 where small_table.width = '1920';
```

or join's from the same table?

```
select big_table.*
from big_table as big_table1
left join big_table big_table2
ON (big_table1.id=big_table2.id and  `big_table1`.`height` = '1080')
left join big_table 
ON (big_table.id=big_table1.id)
where big_table1.width = '1920';
```

or there is some better solution, better select's?
 (on both tables I can use indexes (width and height), but only ID is unique)

Comment: So what is it that you are trying to achieve exactly? What should it do and what will be the result of that?

Comment: try `$sql='...';
$msc=microtime(true);
$mysql_query($sql);
$msc=microtime(true)-$msc;
echo $msc.' seconds';  
echo ($msc*1000).' milliseconds';  `

Comment: first would be faster as it getting data form only one table

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349270/in-what-way-does-denormalization-improve-database-performance

Comment: The second query is using a table that doesn't exist, `small_table_ratio`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No join is faster that join. If you have a proper index (that is, a single index on the combination of `width` and `height`) then the simple select on `big_table` will be way faster.

Comment: Seeing as he is probably joining on `sub_category_id` and `category_id`, he will just move the bottleneck to somewhere else, and the overall performance will decrease, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Query execution time, is not the only parameter to take into consideration.
If any other table would have to join `big_table`, it would kill performance on those joins.

For scalability, I would defiantly split the tables, having the data separated will ensure you, that a bottleneck won't arise here.

Make sure you put *least used data* in a table for itself, and most commonly used data in the other. If you have a huge `text`, putting this in the least used table, would be good as well.