# SQL tables and data redundancy

Tags: sql, database

Is data redundancy in SQL tables ever acceptable in real world application. Apart from making it easier to query from tables, should one always try to reduce data redundancy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349270/in-what-way-does-denormalization-improve-database-performance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In what way does denormalization improve database performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349270/in-what-way-does-denormalization-improve-database-performance)

Comment: Of course it is.   If it weren't about 80% of real world applications would be out of compliance.  However, it needs to be done judiciously, consciously, and for good reasons.

Comment: In order of increasing effort, you can eliminate redundant data, work to keep it all consistent, or fix it after it gets inconsistent. Your database, your time, your choice.